# I want to implement the code in the same way as the image, but what should I do?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

[image]

I want to implement the code in the same way as the image, but what should I do?

Comment: Maybe search for the [TU Delft LaTeX template for reports and theses](https://de.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/delft-university-of-technology-thesis-and-report), which is intended to be both an example and ...

Comment: Or have a look at the [`fncychap` documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf)